# Route traffic from one network to Charles Proxy hosted on another network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy

Is it possible to push traffic from clients on my network to a charles proxy server hosted on another network? I am of course able to push traffic from say my mobile device to my Charles Proxy if it I run Charles locally, but I want to know if it is possible if the Charles server is hosted on another network.

Comment: Routing traffic between networks is a well documented process. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Well, I recently came to find out that using ssh traffic can be forwarded, but this proves a little more difficult for mobile devices. I want to be able to just point to an external IP hosting the proxy and push the traffic there for my use case.

Comment: This site does not entertain questions regarding mobile devices except insofar as those mobile devices interact directly with PCs. You may wish to find the OS-specific sisters sites for your mobile device. There is one for Android and one for iOS/Apple devices.